# If the power steering disabled, can driving without power steering fluid still cause damage to the pump?

Tags: power-steering, power-steering-fluid

I know the pump may be damaged if attempting to use the power steering without fluid. However, what if the power steering is disabled by removing the corresponding fuse below the steering wheel?

*Vehicle in question is a 2001 Ford Ikon (Fiesta sedan essentially) - very simple mechanically.*

Comment: Is this an electrohydraulical power steering system? An electric pump providing the hydraulic pressure? Older cars had fully hydraulic systems with mechanically driven pumps, so you wouldn't remove the fuse, you would remove the belt.

Comment: Cars with power steering were meant to be driven with it working, you can steer them without it but often it's very, very heavy and should not be done routinely

Comment: @juhist, thanks for the informative comment! It is indeed a purely hydraulic power steering system. I couldn't find any fuse correlating to the power steering in the manual. I presume I should delete this question, then?